# How to Integrate Contentful and Next.js App Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router, next.js13, app-router

I found  difficulty in integrating Contentful and next js router.  here is my Folder structure. The contentful https://www.contentful.com/  Content and models :
[image]
[image]

[image]

My error is i cannot access the content that i given in contentful, API is working though.

```
Source
src\app\utils\getContent.jsx (9:27) @ async getContent

   7 | });
   8 |
>  9 | const { items, total } = await client.getEntries({
     |                         ^
  10 |   content_type: contentType,
  11 |   ...rest,
  12 | });
Call Stack
```

To get the resources , this is resources / [slug]/ Page.jsx

```js
import Button from "../components/Button/Button";
import { createClient } from "contentful";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { GoArrowLeft } from "react-icons/go";

const client = createClient({
  space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
  accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY,
});

export async function generateMetaData({ params }) {
  try {
    const resource = await fetchResource(params);
    if (!resource)
      return {
        title: "404 Not Found",
        description:
          "The resource you are looking for does not exist or it has been removed.",
      };
    return {
      title: resource.fields.title,
      description: resource.fields.description,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      title: "404 Not Found",
      description:
        "The resource you are looking for does not exist or it has been removed.",
    };
  }
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const res = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "resource",
  });

  return res.items.map((item) => ({
    slug: item.fields.slug,
  }));
}

async function fetchResource({ slug }) {
  const res = await client.getEntries(
    {
      content_type: "resource",
      "fields.slug": slug,
    },
    {
      revalidate: 345600, // Add revalidation here
    }
  );

  return res.items[0];
}

export default async function ResourceDetails({ params }) {
  const resource = await fetchResource(params);

  return (
    <section className="mt-8">
      <Link scroll={false} href="/" className="flex items-center gap-x-1 pl-2">
        <GoArrowLeft color="#F7F7F7" size={24} />
        <span className=" font-semibold text-text text-base">Back</span>
      </Link>
      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row mt-5 gap-x-10 lg:gap-x-16 justify-center items-center">
        <div className=" bg-super-dark-gray flex relative items-center justify-center md:pb-[25%] md:pt-[25%] pt-[50%] pb-[50%] rounded-2xl w-full md:w-1/2 border-4 border-outline border-opacity-15">
          <div className="absolute w-2/3 rounded-3xl overflow-hidden  shadow-shine bg-transparent bg-opacity-0 ">
            <Image
              priority={true}
              alt={resource.fields.title}
              src={"https:" + resource.fields.thumbnail.fields.file.url}
              className="h-full w-full"
              width={800}
              height={800}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full mt-12 md:mt-0 md:w-1/2">
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-3 items-start">
            <h1 className="text-h4 xl:text-h3 font-bold">
              {resource.fields.title}
            </h1>
            <p className=" text-text text-base xl:text-h6 2xl:text-h5 max-w-[50ch] text-balance pb-3 ">
              {resource.fields.description}
            </p>
            <Button
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
              href={resource.fields.link}
            >
              View Source
            </Button>
          </div>

          <div className="flex flex-col gap-x-2 mt-12 divide-y-2 divide-outline divide-opacity-20 text-xs xl:text-base 2xl:text-h6">
            <div className=" gap-x-1 grid grid-cols-12 border-t-2 border-outline border-opacity-20 py-2">
              <h2 className=" font-semibold col-span-4">Category</h2>
              <span className=" col-span-8 text-text px-1">
                {resource.fields.category.fields.category}
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className=" gap-x-1 grid grid-cols-12 ">
              <h2 className=" font-semibold col-span-4 pt-2">Tags</h2>
              <span className="flex flex-col col-span-8  text-text">
                {resource.fields.tags.map((tag) => (
                  <span
                    className=" py-2 border-b-2 border-outline border-opacity-20 px-1"
                    key={tag.sys.id}
                  >
                    {tag.fields.tag}
                  </span>
                ))}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

To fetch the data from Contentful , getContext.jsx.

```js
import { createClient } from "contentful";

export async function getContent({ contentType, ...rest }) {
  const client = createClient({
    space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  });

  const { items, total } = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: contentType,
    ...rest,
  });

  return { items, total };
}
```

How to get my contents from the Contentful, resolve this issues?

```
Error: {
  "status": 400,
  "statusText": "Bad Request",
  "message": "The query you sent was invalid. Probably a filter or ordering specification is not applicable to the type of a field.",
  "details": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "name": "unknownContentType",
        "value": "DOESNOTEXIST"
      }
    ]
  },
  "request": {
    "url": "https://cdn.contentful.com:443/spaces/rc1o9lpsn7t5/environments/master/entries",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/vnd.contentful.delivery.v1+json",
      "X-Contentful-User-Agent": "sdk contentful.js/10.8.5; platform node.js/v20.11.0; os Windows/v20.11.0;",
      "Authorization": "Bearer ...dOUFY",
      "User-Agent": "axios/1.6.8",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br"
    },
    "method": "get"
```

Comment: Please share the full error you are seeing. Also try outputing the response from get entries without the object destruction.

Comment: @DevonRay i edited and shared above..

Comment: Judging by your content type should it not be Net-Ninja instead of resourcesPage

Comment: @DevonRay i have done the whole process again by creating different space, content type, contents. now the content type is "resource" not  Net-Ninja.  I gave the env.local    CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID , CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN . the error appears in getContext.jsx  which shows  the error in this line  const { items, total } = await client.getEntries({

Comment: What is the error message now.

Comment: @DevonRay its same error til now

Answer (score 1):

According to the **Contentful** [docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/typescript-in-javascript-client-library/) the `getEntries` function returns **only** one value.

Try this instead:

```
const items = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: contentType,
    ...rest,
});
```

And please make sure the `contentType` is valid

Comment: even i give the one value is not working and gives me the same error..